# Increasing distances among nodes in NetworkX

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx, pos

I'm trying to create a network of approximately 6500 nodes for retweets. The shape of network looks so bad with a very low distance among node. I've tried spring_layout to increase the distances but it didn't change anything.

```
nx.draw(G, with_labels=False, node_color=color_map_n, node_size=5,layout=nx.spring_layout(G,k=100000))
```

[image: my network]

Answer (score 0):

I swapped "layout=..." with "pos=..." and it worked